# Variant of burst balloon

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

Given N balloons, if you burst ith balloon you get Ai−1∗Ai+1 coins and then (i-1)th and (i+1)th balloons become adjacent. Find maximum number of coins you can gather. 
If you have single balloon then you will get value written on it. 
Example 
if you have 4 balloons and coins associated for them are.... 
1 2 3 4 then you will get 20 maximum.

Comment: In my case, I have a solution of n^2 * n! which is too slow for n=10.

Comment: What if two balloons left? How to get 20 in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion:

```
def bustbaloon(i, arr):
    if i >= len(arr):
        return 0
    mini = 0
    for j in range(i,len(arr)):
        left = 1
        right = 1
        if j > 0:
            left = arr[j-1]
        if j < len(arr) -1:
            right = arr[j+1]
        center = arr.pop(j)
#         print(left,right,  center,i, arr)
        count = left * center * right + bustbaloon(0,arr)
        
        arr.insert(j,center)
        mini = max(mini , count)
    return mini
    
res = bustbaloon(0,[1,2,3,4,5] )
```

Source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/burst-balloon-to-maximize-coins/